# cannot use CircleFlowIndicator with RealViewSwitcher

Tags: android, view

I downloaded a view called viewflow from https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow and I want to use only the CircleFlowIndicator from it to connect it with my RealViewSwitcher so I want to modify the code but when I try to use the class CircleFlowIndicator  I found

```
int activeType = a.getInt(R.styleable.CircleFlowIndicator_activeType,
                STYLE_FILL);
```

cause the error Resource not found I mean R.styleable cause the error I want to know how can I solve the problem , I try to copy the \res\values\attrs.xml but I didn't benefit from that and I see the file \bin\R.txt

```
int attr activeColor 0x7f010001
int attr activeType 0x7f010007
int attr centered 0x7f010004
int attr clipPadding 0x7f010009
int attr customTypeface 0x7f010012
int attr fadeOut 0x7f010005
int attr footerColor 0x7f010010
int attr footerLineHeight 0x7f01000f
int attr footerTriangleHeight 0x7f010011
int attr inactiveColor 0x7f010002
int attr inactiveType 0x7f010006
int attr radius 0x7f010003
int attr selectedBold 0x7f01000b
int attr selectedColor 0x7f01000a
int attr selectedSize 0x7f01000c
int attr sidebuffer 0x7f010000
int attr textColor 0x7f01000d
int attr textSize 0x7f01000e
int attr titlePadding 0x7f010008
int drawable icon 0x7f020000
int id fill 0x7f030001
int id stroke 0x7f030000
int string app_name 0x7f040001
int string hello 0x7f040000
int[] styleable CircleFlowIndicator { 0x7f010001, 0x7f010002, 0x7f010003, 0x7f010004, 0x7f010005, 0x7f010006, 0x7f010007 }
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_activeColor 0
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_activeType 6
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_centered 3
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_fadeOut 4
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_inactiveColor 1
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_inactiveType 5
int styleable CircleFlowIndicator_radius 2
int[] styleable TitleFlowIndicator { 0x7f010008, 0x7f010009, 0x7f01000a, 0x7f01000b, 0x7f01000c, 0x7f01000d, 0x7f01000e, 0x7f01000f, 0x7f010010, 0x7f010011, 0x7f010012 }
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_clipPadding 1
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_customTypeface 10
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_footerColor 8
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_footerLineHeight 7
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_footerTriangleHeight 9
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_selectedBold 3
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_selectedColor 2
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_selectedSize 4
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_textColor 5
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_textSize 6
int styleable TitleFlowIndicator_titlePadding 0
int[] styleable ViewFlow { 0x7f010000 }
int styleable ViewFlow_sidebuffer 0
```

which I think may be useful but I didn't understand it , can any one help my to use CircleFlowIndicator with my RealViewSwitcher